# Flex Chart : Horizontal line at 0 when having negative values

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a Flex Column Chart, which shows bars with each positive and negative values.
I only want to have a horizontal line at 0 to distinguish between positive and negative values.

I turned off all the axis.

How could I achieve to get this line?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a GridLines instance to the backgroundElements array property of your chart:

```
<mx:backgroundElements>
               <mx:GridLines 
                    direction="horizontal" 
                    horizontalShowOrigin="true"
                    horizontalChangeCount="{int.MAX_VALUE}">

                    <mx:horizontalOriginStroke>
                        <mx:Stroke weight="1" />
                    </mx:horizontalOriginStroke>

                </mx:GridLines>
            </mx:backgroundElements>
```

Alternatively, rather than setting the horizontalChangeCount to a huge value, you could use a horizontal stroke that is invisible (alpha = 0 or somesuch).